# How to implement a custom menu without tabs?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

http://i1254.photobucket.com/albums/hh620/Mike_Mccone/menu.png

I have a menu, linked above, that I would like to appear in all my activities. I can obviously include the xml for the menu in each of my activity layouts, and code my listeners in every activity, but I'd rather not have to do that to all 15 or so of my activities.

I tried creating and extending a custom base activity, to no avail, as I then couldn't set a different layout for each activity.

What's the best way to implement a menu like this without using tabs?

Comment: I would try subclassing a View and not an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using Fragments or Actionbar(Sherlock) you could do it probably like that:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    private FrameLayout mContainer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Layout that has menu on top and an empty
        // FrameLayout below
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        // add click listeners to menu and let them call
        // onMenuItemClicked() or whatever you wish to do
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        mContainer.addView(view);
    }

    protected void onMenuItemClicked(){ /* or abstract */ }
}
```

Set a layout containing the menu on top and something empty below (e.g. `FrameLayout`) and override `setContentView` so that it sets the content inside the empty layout.

Then base your activities on this class and use as usual. Maybe add menu button handling.